# How can I allow an if statment to access a capture group from an above regex?

Tags: regex, perl, vmware

I have an if statement inside a while loop to filter out filenames that are *.iso and not *.vmdk. It works...sorta, there is just one little issue I can't figure out. When I run the code and there is a match to the if statement in the loop it makes the hash entry just like it should but because it does not know the channel number of the IDE interface it just calls the hash entry "IDE" rather than "IDE0" or "IDE1".

Here is my code,

```
        foreach my $vm (@virtual_machines) {
        my $vmx_file = $ssh1->capture("cat $virtual_machines{$vm}{VMX}");
        my $disk_count = -1;
        my $port;
        while ($vmx_file =~ m/^(ide(?<PORT>[0-1])\:[0-1])\.fileName\s+=\s+"(?<DISK>[^"]+)["]/xmg) {
$port = "$+{port}";
            if ("$+{DISK}" =~ m/\/vmfs\/volumes\/.+?\/(?<ISO>.+?\.iso)/xm) {
                ++$disk_count;
                $virtual_disks{$vm}{"IDE$+{PORT}"}{"Disk$disk_count"} = "$+{ISO}";
            } else {
                ++$disk_count;
                $virtual_disks{$vm}{"IDE$+{PORT}"}{"Disk$disk_count"} = "$+{DISK}";
            }
        }
    }
```

Like I said above, the code works except for that one part. Is the way I am approaching this wrong? Do I need to make something like a loop that looks for 2 matches or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are clobbering the `$+` variable when you do your second regex match (the one in the `if`).  You should save off `$+{PORT}` before the `if`.

**EDIT**: this demo describes what is happening in your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "hi 1234 bye";
$string =~ /(?<num>\d+)/;
print $+{num}, "\n";
$string =~ /./;
print $+{num} || "Clobbered", "\n";
```

prints:

```
1234
Clobbered
```

Comment: I changed my code to what you recommended and it works perfect, thanks for the help. I was pretty sure it was something simple.

Comment: @Solignis, no problem.  I've added a snippet of code to demonstrate what is going on.  The match variables are reset each time a regex operator is used.